# Bucle While con if y else para ambos

Tags: python, while

estoy empezando en python, y aunque algunas cosas las tengo claras, con otras que creo que son fáciles me quedo estancado.
En este caso tengo un bucle while con un if dentro, el problema que recibo es error de sintaxis pero le he dado unas cuantas vueltas y no consigo solucionarlo.
Creo que el problema es que hay dos "else", uno para el if y otro para el while y no lo estoy escribiendo correctamente.

```
numero = 19
intento = 0
max_intentos = 3
while intento < max_intentos:
    number = int(input("Adivina el numero: "))
    intento += 1
if number == numero:
    print("Enhorabuena adivinaste el numero")
break
else:
    print("Has fallado vuelve a intentarlo")
else:
    print("No tienes mas oportunidades")
```

Gracias,

Comment: While no tiene una parte `else`

Comment: sería bueno que explicaras qué quieres que haga el código y qué no hace, para así entender mejor el objetivo final. Ten en cuenta también que la identación es fundamental en Python, por lo que ahora mismo el `if` se ejecutará _después_ del `while`, no dentro de él, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No se si tuvistes problemas al traspasar tu código a esta página, pero parece estar mal indentado.

Esta versión, con la indentación correcta, funciona:

```
numero = 19
intento = 0
max_intentos = 3
while intento < max_intentos:
    number = int(input("Adivina el numero: "))
    intento += 1
    if number == numero:
        print("Enhorabuena adivinaste el numero")
        break
    else:
        print("Has fallado vuelve a intentarlo")
else:
    print("No tienes mas oportunidades")
```

Recuerda que en Python se usa la indentación para indicar el anidamiento. La idea es que las instrucciones que forman parte de `while`, `for`, `if` y otras similares comiencen en un margen izquierdo cuatro espacios más a la derecha.

```
if condicion:
   inst1
   inst2
   ...
   instN
else:
   inst_else1
   inst_else2
   ...
   inst_elseN
```

La regla se aplica recursivamente. Asi, un if dentro de un while es:

```
while condicion:
    if otra_condicion:
        instrucciones
    else:
        instrucciones_else
else: # del while
   instrucciones_else_while
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió y ademas me aclaraste lo del indentado.